# Linking .Net Assemblies

Tags: .net, visual-studio, assemblies, linker, al.exe

This is all hypothetical, so please bear with me.

Say I'm writing a tool in C# called Foo.  The output is foo.exe.  I've found some really great library that I like to use called Bar, which I can reference as bar.dll in my project.  When I build my project, I have foo.exe and bar.dll in my output directory.  Good so far.

What I'd like to do is link foo.exe and bar.dll so they are one assembly, foo.exe.  I would prefer to be able to do this in VS2008, but if I have to resort to a command-line tool like al.exe I don't mind so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's ILMerge. [Link](http://research.microsoft.com/~mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Set up a post-build event under Project Properties:

ilmerge /out:$(TargetDir)foo.exe $(TargetPath) $(TargetDir)bar.dll

Answer (score 2):

Check out the ILMerge tool found [here](http://research.microsoft.com/~mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone who answered!

I ended up with [NuGenUnify](http://www.genetibase.com/cforce/nugenunify.php) which provides a GUI wrapper for ilmerge.